# MongoDb division not working in query

Tags: mongodb

This is how my data looks like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5919f19716e64ad662bd753b"),
  "cardNumber" : "11111111115523",
  "transID" : "5645344133546",
  "transDate" : "1/1/16",
  "merchant" : "Publix",
  "mtype" : "Groceries",
  "merchantCode" : "1",
  "transAmount" : 100
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5919f20416e64ad662bd753c"),
  "cardNumber" : "11111111115523",
  "transID" : "5645344136544",
  "transDate" : "1/4/16",
  "merchant" : "Sears",
  "mtype" : "Clothing and Shoes",
  "merchantCode" : "2",
  "transAmount" : 150.66
}
 /* 3 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5919f20c16e64ad662bd753d"),
  "cardNumber" : "11111111115523",
  "transID" : "564535522233344",
  "transDate" : "1/4/16",
  "merchant" : "Shell",
  "mtype" : "Gasoline / Fuel",
  "merchantCode" : "3",
  "transAmount" : 25
}
```

The result I'm looking for is:
 the sum of all "transAmount" multiplied by 100 and divided by the total that the person spent (ex: (totalByCategories)*100/(sumOfAllTransactiosAmount)) and then the output needs to be ordered by "merchantCode" so that each subset has the category and the correspondent result of the operation.
I got them to work individually but when I try to make the full query it gives an error code 16420 aggregate failed.

Here is how my query looks like:

```
var denominator = db.getCollection('Transactions').aggregate({
$group: { 
    "_id": null, 
    "total": {$sum:"$transAmount"}
  }
}, { $project: {_id:0, total: "$total"}});

db.getCollection('Transactions').aggregate([{
$group: { 
    _id: '$merchantCode', 
    total: {
        $sum: { $multiply: ['$transAmount', 100 ]}

 }}},
   { $project: { 

       percentage: { 
         $divide: [ 
           "$total", 
          denominator
          ] 
      } 
   }
 }
])
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: what is the value of `denominator` there?

Comment: in this case with that data only is 275.66 because is the sum of all "transAmount" but in the operation I believe is undefined for some reason and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Aggregate returns a "cursor" and not a single response. You are trying to assign this to a singular value of `denominator`. Instead you want `var denominator = db.getCollection('Transactions').aggregate({ "$group": { "_id": null, "total": { "$sum": "$transAmount" } }}).toArray()[0].amount` Which is just the value of the `total` property from the single element array response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it to work perfectly by adding "denominator.toArray()[0].total" in the operation itself. Regards and Happy coding!